# Create this model instance automatically after creating the User model instance

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, inheritance, django-orm

I want the UserProfile model object to be created automaticaly when User object is created.

Models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username,password=None,passwordconfirm=None):
       
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
           
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            username=username,
            password=password
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    username=models.CharField(verbose_name='username',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account_created=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username','password']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
            "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
            return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin

class UserProfile(User):
    joined_forums=ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100),default=None,blank=True)
    user_profile_picture=models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_pictures/",default='user-profile-icon.png')
    recent_interactions=ArrayField(ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200),size=2,blank=True),blank=True)
```

Before I had the User instance as foreign key.Now i have removed that and inherited the User class in UserProfile as Multi-table inheritance.Now I am unable to migrate and its asking for default values for the pointer to the User instance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you want to do you have to use post_save signal method of the User Model and once the User Object is saved create the instance of the UserProfile and save it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/) or you can use [django-annoying's](https://pypi.org/project/django-annoying/) AutoOneToOneField. If you are using Signals, add a user field to the UserProfile Model in order to create some form of relationship to your User model. django-annoying's is also a good option.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use `post_save` signal which provides functionality after saving the user instance also you can create a user profile instance

#### but, here I can see you are using a customized user model so, no need to use `post_save` signal you can directly create a user profile instance with `_create_user` method of BaseUserManager like this...

```py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self,username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        values = [email]
        field_value_map = dict(zip(self.model.REQUIRED_FIELDS, values))
        for field_name, value in field_value_map.items():
            if not value:
                raise ValueError("The {} value must be set".format(field_name))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=user) # This is tricky part for create User Profile
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", False)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", False)
        return self._create_user(email,username, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_staff=True.")
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_superuser=True.")

        return self._create_user(email, username, password, **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    username=models.CharField(verbose_name='username',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account_created=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username','password']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
            "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
            return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer:

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    joined_forums=ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100),default=None,blank=True)
    user_profile_picture=models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_pictures/",default='user-profile-icon.png')
    recent_interactions=ArrayField(ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200),size=2,blank=True),blank=True)
```